# Let $L = \{w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid \text{$\#_a(w)$ is odd and $\#_b(w)$ is even}\}$. Prove that $L^*$ is the set of strings where $\#_b(w)$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Let
\begin{align}
L &= \{w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid \text{the number of $a$'s in $w$ is odd}\\
&\qquad\text{and the number of $b$'s is even}\}.
\end{align}

Prove that $L^*$ is the set of strings where the number of $b$'s is even.

$\epsilon$ = empty string

let $\#_b(w)$ = number of $b$'s in string $w$

$\#_a(w)$ = number of $a$'s in string  $w$

I started my proof with this :

**Step Base**.

Let $L^0 = \{\epsilon\}$, therefore , the number of $b$'s is even because $\#_b$(w) = $2n$ where $n = 0$.

But now, i'm confused, I don't know how to continue with the inductive step
I think the induction hypothesis is to suppose that $L^n$ has an even number of $b$'s and make the proof on $L^{n+1}$.

How can I proceed with the inductive step?.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not true. Indeed, if $w = ba^2b$, then $\#_b(w)$ is even, but $w \notin L^*$.